# WSUS Windows Update keeps recommending same updates on Windows 7

Tags: windows-update, wsus

A Windows 7 Ultimate PC is connected to a WSUS intranet server, like a lot of other PCs here which are functioning fine.

The same 3 updates keep presenting themselves as avaiable for installation, even when they have been successfully installed and the PC rebooted.  The Control Panel shows these updates have been installed okay.

There is a MS KB article on how to troubleshoot this problem, but they suggest manually installing downloaded updates in Safe Mode, which is impossible in Windows 7 (Ultimate), as the Windows Installer won't operate in Safe Mode.

I performed a clean boot with disabled non-MS services, and disabled startup items, manually installed the downloaded updates, rebooted, and Windows Update again said they were available for install on the next boot.

There are no errors in the Event Log, the PC has plenty of space, and when I run the manually downloaded update installers, I do so as the domain admin.  The PC is running Symantec End Point protection, which all other PCs are running and have no problem with.

The updates in question have installed on another PC running Windows 7 Professsional.

I don't think we have any other PCs running Win7 Ultimate except the problem PC in this thread.

Comment: Which updates keep being re-offered?  Which MS KB article did you follow for troubleshooting?  If you force Windows to check with Windows Update instead of WSUS does it also offer the same updates?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339/
The updates keep being offered through Windows Update on the PC.  They are: kb2487367, kb2468871, kb2533523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has since resolved itself.

- wsusutil /reset
- wsusutil /healthcheck

had been run on the WSUS server, which may of resolved any corrupt files.

Answer (score 0):

In WSUS 3.0 SP2 the commands referenced above are as follows.

wsusutil reset
wsusutil checkhealth

Other commands available are 
        help
        configuressl
        configuresslproxy
        deletefrontendserver
        listinactiveapprovals
        removeinactiveapprovals
        export
        healthmonitoring
        import
        listfrontendservers
        movecontent
        usecustomwebsite
        listunreferencedpackagefolders